# Is it possible to make a silent installer for npgsql

Tags: npgsql

We're building a package in LanRev for npgsql. 
Is it possible to make a silent installer? If not, we won't be able to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at this link -> [packages/Npgsql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/)

It also contains a pakage installer command.